# dll library not being injected even though there are no errors

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dll-injection

I'm trying to inject my .dll in a target process. I will give the script a command line argument to launch a certain process then inject the .dll in it. The problem is that the code runs without errors but the .dll is not being injected. The reasons which I believe the .dll is not being injected are that I can delete the .dll when the target process is running. I don't see my .dll when printing the modules used by the target process, and the code in the .dll only writes the word "hello" to a file (other than that there is nothing in the DllMain()) but I don't see that file. I have read tons of posts about dll injection on stackoverflow and I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

My code:

```
if (!CreateProcessW(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    wtext,        // Command line arguments to launch the target process
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    CREATE_SUSPENDED,
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
{
    printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
wstring dllPath = wstring(selfdir) + TEXT("\\HookEngine.dll"); // full path to the .dll
LPCWSTR PathToDll = dllPath.c_str();
size_t nLength = (wcslen(PathToDll)+1) * sizeof(LPCWSTR);
LPVOID lpRemoteString = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, NULL, nLength, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (lpRemoteString == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate memory in the target process, error number (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 1;
}
if (!WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, lpRemoteString, PathToDll, nLength, NULL)) {
    printf("Failed to write memory to the target process, error number (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    VirtualFreeEx(pi.hProcess, lpRemoteString, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 1;
}
LPVOID lpLoadLibraryW = NULL;
lpLoadLibraryW = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"KERNEL32.DLL"), "LoadLibraryW");
if (!lpLoadLibraryW) {
    printf("Load library failed, error number (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 1;
}
HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(pi.hProcess,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpLoadLibraryW,
    lpRemoteString,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
if (!hThread) {
    printf("Creating thread failed, error number (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return 1;
}
else {
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10000);
    HMODULE arr[1024]; // the next few line are for checking which dlls are being used by the target process
    DWORD bneeded = 0;
    wchar_t arr2[1024];
    EnumProcessModulesEx(pi.hProcess, arr, sizeof(arr), &bneeded, LIST_MODULES_ALL);
    for (int i = 0; i < bneeded/sizeof(HMODULE); i++) {
        int len = GetModuleFileNameEx(pi.hProcess, arr[i], arr2, 1024);
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            wcout << arr2[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
}
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
VirtualFreeEx(pi.hProcess, lpRemoteString, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

I don't have any idea why this is not working. No errors are happening so I think it should work.
The script and the dll are in the same folder and I give it the command line argument "python myscript.py". The code in the python script only prints some number on a text file and I can see that file when I run the python script from my code so CreateProcess() is succeeding and the process is being resumed. So, when I run my script it only creates a process and nothing else happens. It is like the code between CreateProcess and ResumeThread() doesn't do anything. What should I do?

Comment: Is `selfdir` an absolute path? Are the target executable, the dll, and your injector all in the same bitness? Also: `sizeof(LPCWSTR)` -> `sizeof(WCHAR)`

Comment: The path is absolute, the target is an executable. And the bitness is the same for the dll and the injector. I will try to change the `sizeof` and see what happens.

Comment: UPD: it didn't work.

Comment: size_t nLength = (wcslen(PathToDll)+1) * sizeof(LPCWSTR);

sizeof(LPCWSTR) is 4 on x86 and 8 on x64, you're getting the size of a pointer not a wide char.  Use `sizeof(wchar_t)` instead.